# How to get modified data from a file in linux?

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I am designing a logger plugin for my tool.I have a busybox syslog on a target board, and i want to get syslog data from it so i can forward to my host(not via remote port forwarding of syslog) via my own communication framework.Initially i had made use of syslog's ability to forward messages it receives to a named pipe but this only works via a patch addition which is not feasible in my case.So now my idea is to write a configuration file in syslog to forward all log messages it receives to a file and track the file to get my data.I can use tail function to monitor my file changes but my busybox tail does not support "--follow" option since syslog performs logrotate which causes "tail -f" to fail.And also i am not sure if this is a good method to do it.So what i wanted to ask is there another way in which i can get modified data from a file.I can use inotify, but that can only be used to track file changes.So is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "diff" utility (or git-diff, which has more facilities).

Comment: I cannot use diff utility since it is used to compare files, but in my case i need to get newly added data from a log file to a memory like Eg: a named pipe, so i retrieve data from this memory and send it my host

Answer (score 0):

You may write a script/program which can receive an inotify event. And the script reopens the file and starts to read till EOF, from the previously saved last read file position.

Comment: but syslog logrotates its file so this could work until my file is logrotated in which case my file's last read position would become invalid and also inotify will block for an event,i cannot use blocking call since my logger program is a part of the communication framework where blocking calls are not feasible.

Comment: For log rotate, I guess a max size would have been specified. You can modify your seek position depending on this max seek. And inotify can give you the start and end of the latest change.